# Process.Start and "The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: .net-4.0, process, mapped-drive

I am trying to run a console application from a mapped drive (T:\ is a mapped drive for a shared network folder) and get the error:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

Why do I get this error? The administrator credentials are correct.

```
var password = new SecureString();
password.AppendChar(Convert.ToChar("P"));
password.AppendChar(Convert.ToChar("a"));
password.AppendChar(Convert.ToChar("a"));
password.AppendChar(Convert.ToChar("s"));
Process.Start(@"t:\ca\test.exe"), "", "Administrator", password, "domain");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the mapped drive `T:` is also correctly mapped for the `Administrator` account.

Also, I'm not sure, but the Administrator must probably be logged in for the mapped drive to be available.

You could also try the following, starting `cmd.exe`, mapping your UNC path and then calling the application:

```
var password = new SecureString();
password.AppendChar(Convert.ToChar("P"));
password.AppendChar(Convert.ToChar("a"));
password.AppendChar(Convert.ToChar("a"));
password.AppendChar(Convert.ToChar("s"));

var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.UserName = "Administrator";
startInfo.Password = password;
startInfo.Domain = "domain";

var process = Process.Start(startInfo);

process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"pushd \\your_unc_path\ca");
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("test.exe");
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");

process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: How to do that? I have mapped network drive from the same account on which I run app.

Comment: If you're already logged in with the Administrator account why do you call `Process.Start` with that account?

Comment: I get "The publisher could not be verified" security dialog, I thought that if I run app with admin credentials the dialog will not be shown.