# C# “The system cannot find the path specified” on Share Drive

Tags: c#, windows

I am creating a Windows Application using C# which access a mapped drive (**Z:**\ is a mapped drive for a shared network folder) to grab the files inside the folder but return an exception error :

> The system cannot find the path specified.

I have two different functions that will access this mapped drive. One function will display the image file found inside the shared drive to the windows application. Codes as below :

**Display image file :**

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(photoPath))
                {
                    pbImg1.ImageLocation = photoPath;
                }
                else
                {
                    pbImg1.Image = eMapViewer.Properties.Resources.TempImage;
                }
```

When double click on the image file on the windows application, the codes will call for another function to open the actual files on map drive :

**Double click to open image file :**

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(photoPath))
            {
                Process.Start(@photoPath);
            }
```

The first function **(Display Image File)** works without any issues. The image file is able to be displayed on the windows application. However, the second function **(Double click to open actual image file)** returns the exception error. I can confirm that both functions use the same photoPath of :

> \\AOI\Backup\Mapping\picture.bmp

I was referring to this thread I found but cannot find the solution. [Process.Start and "The system cannot find the path specified"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310294/process-start-and-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified)

Can someone help on this?

Comment: So is the path `Z:\...` or `\\AOI\Backup\...`?

Comment: @Klaus Gütter both path is the same. The \\AOI\Backup is the Z:\ drive

Comment: I did not ask if they point to the same directory but which of the two forms is used. Not all code accepts UNC.